# How to determine a row index from a datatable that shares a column with a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, datatable

I have a `combobox` and a `datatable`.

I've added all of the elements of one column in the `datatable` to the `combobox` items.
Now whenever the user chooses a item in the combobox, I want to go to the `datatable` and compare the column, if there's a match, it will do some code.

I have the following

```
        private void comboBox8_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = comboBox8.SelectedItem.ToString();
       int z = 0;
        foreach (var row in datatable.Rows)
        {
            int i = 0; i++;

            if (datatable.Rows[row]["Cidade"] == str)
            {

                z = i;
            }

        }
    }
```

"Cidade" is the column name that matches the options in the combobox.
The Problem is that the code doesn't identify the ìf` condition as valid, saying there are invalid arguments

Edit: worked it around like this:

```
 private void comboBox8_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = comboBox8.SelectedItem.ToString();

        int z = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < DataAccess.Instance.tabelasismica.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            if (DataAccess.Instance.tabelasismica.Rows[i]["Cidade"] == str)
            {

                z = i;
            }

        }
        MessageBox.Show(z.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(DataAccess.Instance.tabelasismica.Rows[z]["Cidade"].ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard way of doing things like this is to use data-binding. You'd simply set your ComboBox's DataSource to your DataTable. The code would roughly look like this:

```
comboBox8.DataSource = datatable;
comboBox8.DisplayMember = "Cidade"
comboBox8.ValueMember = "PrimaryKeyColumnOfYourTable"
```

Now in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, you simply use `comboBox8.SelectedValue` property to get the ID of the selected row. If you have strongly typed DataSet, your DataTable will have a function named `FindByYourPKColumn()` that you can use to find the row using this ID.

Comment: By "primarykeycolumn" you mean a column filled with integers? What is a "strongly typed" dataset? I've been avoiding datasets since i've been getting the same thing done with individual datatables

Comment: @ng80092b: A Primary Key column doesn't need to be integer, it just needs to be the primary key of your table. You may want to consult some basic RDBMS book to find more details on that. About strongly typed DataSets, the only real thing involved in your case is the `DataTable` itself. The only issue is that built-in DataSet designer doesn't work with isolated DataTables, so even if you have a single table, you'll need to create a DataSet to let the designer provide you the designer surface (to drag-n-drop your tables and do other things).

Comment: The Primary Key in a data table is the unique identifier for the data row. No other row in that data table is allowed to have the same unique identifier. Not all data tables will have a primary key, but it is a common design feature to prevent duplicate data entry and to provide for data row identification.

Answer (score 1):

`datatable.Rows[row]["Cidade"]` is of type `object` - you need to convert it to a string before comparing it to str, like this:

```
if (datatable.Rows[row]["Cidade"].ToString() == str)
{ ... }
```

Comment: Thank you, but i solved it with a `for` cycle without setting it to a string.. I will edit my answer and show how i worked it around. Can you take a look and explain why with the `for` cycle i didnt need to set it to a string?

Comment: I've just tried the way you suggested, it gives an error anyways :p

Comment: the problem is that he doesnt recognize row as a integer, so he doesnt cycle, any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in place of the for loop

```
foreach (DataRow row in dDataAccess.Instance.tabelasismica.Rows)
  {
      if (row["Cidade"].ToString() == str)
      {
          z = dDataAccess.Instance.tabelasismica.Rows.IndexOf(row);
      }
  }
```

or

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
  {
      if (row["Cidade"].ToString() == str)
      {
          z = dataTable.Rows.IndexOf(row);;
      }
  }
```

Being said that, standard practice in using ComboBoxes, ListBoxes etc with datasources is to to have a distinct column in the data-table assigned as the ValueMember of the ComboBox, which makes life even easier - as suggested by @dotNET.

```
comboBox8.DataSource= dataTable; //the data table which contains data
comboBox8.ValueMember = "id";   // column name which you want in SelectedValue
comboBox8.DisplayMember = "name"; // column name that you need to display as text
```

That way you don't have to iterate through the dataTable to find the index of the row, and you can use the ID (`ValueMember`) to continue process as required.

Example [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataset/dataset-combobox.htm)

Answer (score 1):

@dotNET's answer is the preferred method to solve your specific problem.

However to solve the general problem find a value in a dataset your best bets are to either

Use the ADO.NET methods [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd48eyk(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) e.g.

```
var results = dataset.Select(string.Format("Cidade = {0}",str));
if (results.Count() != 0 )
{
      ...
}
```

Or use [System.Data.DataSetExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx)

```
if (datatable.AsEnumerable().Any( x=> x.Field<string>("Cidade") == str ))
{
  ....
}
```